# What happens if you beat the 8-bit intro level in The End is Nigh?

Tags: the-end-is-nigh

When starting a new game in *The End is Nigh*, the game's opening is presented as a Let's Play video of Ash playing his favorite 8-bit game, *The End is Nigh*.

The player is clearly expected to fail here, because soon as you die a single time the game crashes and renders Ash's cartridge unplayable. This means you only get one try to finish the level.

**Is it possible to beat the 8-bit intro level? What happens if I finish it?**

[image: 8-bit intro of The End is Nigh]

Comment: On an unrelated note, the intro level seems to be a throwback to [the *I Wanna be the Guy* level from *Super Meat Boy*](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/PnKP0jcSDiw/maxresdefault.jpg).

Comment: There's a video review somewhere on TEIN that talks about this, McMillen recently retweeted it

Comment: @StevenVascellaro TEIN = The End Is Neigh

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### Yes, it is possible to beat the intro level

(but holy smokes does it seem like a piece of work)

Beating the intro level on Steam will unlock  the secret achievement *Streaming Mimi*. The Nintendo Switch has no trophy support, so it is unlikely you are awarded anything other than satisfaction.

Here's a video showing full completion of the intro.

Comment: Crap on a stick that looks hard

Comment: Nothing happens? Not even storywise? TEIN starts when you die in the arcade game, so I would've thought maybe TEIN doesn't start and you'll get the credits immediately.